# Qt and C++: Overwrite or Expand Class

Tags: c++, qt, class, qpushbutton

I want to add some properties (like an ID) to a `QPushButton`. Therefore,  I need to expand or overwrite the class `Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT QPushButton : public QAbstractButton`

How do I do that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: your id can be as simple as one number/string of a complex struct... what is for your app an id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the use case. There is no problem (and often the intended way) in inheriting from Qt-(Widget) Classes (correct me, if I am wrong).
So you could do:

```
class MyQPushButton : public QPushButton
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     MyQPushButton() : QPushButton(...) {}
private:
    int ID = -1;
}
```

Qt has a very good documentation and you can look at the sources to see what to override.

You could also extend a new class with `QPushButton`, but than you always have to deal with the QPushButton reference in your class, if you want e.g. connect something. In the inherited class you can connect the slots and so on. But for example you could do this:

```
class MyQPushButton 
{
public:
     MyQPushButton() {}
     const QPushButton& const GetQPushButton() { return pushButton; }
     const QPushButton* const GetQPushButtonPtr() { return &pushButton; }

private:
     QPushButton pushButton;
     int ID = -1;
}
```

There is no right and wrong. But I would use the inheritance for Qt-classes.

Answer (score 3):

you dont need to extend the class to just put an id  in it ... instead make use of the [property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html).

as specified in the official [doc here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#reading-and-writing-properties-with-the-meta-object-system):

> A property can be read and written using the generic functions QObject::property() and QObject::setProperty(), without knowing anything about the owning class except the property's name.

you just have to do:

```
ui->myButton->setProperty("Id", 123456);
```

can also be another object e.g a string (or even your own class if you define it to do that)

```
ui->myButton->setProperty("_name", "123456");
```

to read the property is the method `property()` there for you but read the doc because you get a `QVariant` as return example:

```
 QVariant(int, 123456)
```